# Issue with JaCoCo(0.8.7) and Jmockit(1.48)

Tags: jacoco

I am facing ByteCode errors

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at BytecodeReader.java:472

in unit test cases while adding JaCoCo as a coverage tool. The reason for this is the conflict in the JavaAgent used by Jmockit and JaCoCo.

Can anyone please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

There is issue with JaCoCo(0.8.7) and Jmockit(1.48). jaCoCo (0.8.2) and Jmockit(1.48).w ill work seamlessly, I have tested well this.

For this you can downgrade JaCoCo to 0.8.2 and try. It will work.